I am trying to convert .shx files to Python lists
I want to make a world map in pygame, but it doesn't work.
I tried this method of explode():
gdf = gp.read_file('ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shx')

coords = []
for geom in gdf.explode()['geometry']:
    coords.append(list(geom.coords))

but I get the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\002.py", line 11, in <module>
    coords.append(list(geom.coords))
  File "C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 256, in coords
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Component rings have coordinate sequences, but the polygon does not

Anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks
